# Select optional command if Record not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

In rails i am trying to achieve something like :

`@user = User.find(params[:id]) || current_user`

ie: if `User.find(params[:id])` doesn't find an existing record i want the `@user` to store the `current_user`

I think this might rather be a simple thing. But i just started off with ruby on rails.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `User.find(params[:id])` will raise an exception if a `User` isn't found. I'd look up a way to rescue an exception and run code if one is raised.

Comment: Tried your way.... It works.. Thanks..But i think i am gonna go with `find_by_id` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ptd is right - throwing an exception is Rails intention, because it's equivalent SQL `where` clause with passed id - and because of this Rails expected that record with such `id` exists. But instead of `rescue`-ing (I believe it's more pythonic way) I think you can use such code:

`@user = User.find_by_id(params[:id]) || current_user`

Comment: Beat me to it. I was just writing the same thing.